# not able to install blackberry webworks playbook sdk?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I am getting error at the installation time, how to resolve the issue?
Pleas find the image,[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, i changed the text in adobereadme file from 3.2 to 7.1.1